# Вытащить содержание скобки, где есть определенное слово регулярные выражения js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, match

Здравствуйте.

Никак не получается написать правильно регулярку. Есть такая строка:

```
[name {__rpl__} attr="null" just-attr]    [name {__rpl__} attr="just-attr"] [name attr-text]
```

Если написать регулярку примерно так:

```
/(\[name+(.+?)(\{__rpl__\})[^\]]\])/gi
```

То результат будет примерно такой:

```
[name {__rpl__} attr="null" just-attr],
[name {__rpl__} attr="just-attr"],
[name attr-text]
```

Подскажите, как исправить регулярку так, чтоб выводилось только те значения, в которых присутствуют `{__rpl__}`, и которые начинаются на `[name` и заканчивается это всем `]`

У меня не получается сделать проверку на `{__rpl__}`. Т.к. такая регулярка:

```
/(\[name+(.+?)(\{__rpl__\})[^\]]\])/gi
```

приводит к `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/\[name\s[^\]]*{__rpl__}[^\]]*\]/gi
```

[Онлайн-демо](https://regex101.com/r/fLadV9/1/)

- `\[` - символ `[`
- `name` - подстрока `name`
- `\s` - 1 пробельный символ (можно заменить на `\b`, границу слова, или удалить, если не нужна проверка целого слова)
- `[^\]]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `]`
- `{__rpl__}` - подстрока `{__rpl__}`
- `[^\]]*` - 0 и более символов, отличных от `]`
- `\]` - символ `]`

```js
var rx = /\[name\s[^\]]*{__rpl__}[^\]]*\]/gi;
var s = '[name {__rpl__} attr="null" just-attr]    [name {__rpl__} attr="just-attr"] [name attr-text]';
console.log(s.match(rx));
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает отлично!